# Laravel, composer install, don't install laravel/framework upgrade to 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

What is wrong with my `composer.json` configuration.

Tried To Upgrade To ***5.6***, ***5.7*** As Well Same Issue With Them Also. I googled for answers and follow along and also I check every possible line

Eroor:

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
- yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v8.13.7 requires illuminate/view 5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.48], illuminate/view[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2,v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27,v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].

Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "7.0.*",
    "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^2.1.1",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0",
    "arcanedev/no-captcha": "^5.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Helpers\\": "app/Helpers/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Comment: That version of `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` doesn't seem to work with Laravel 5.8. Consider upgrading that plugin (if possible)

Answer (score 4):

This package([yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle)) is not compatible with your Laravel Framework version, That's the reason You got an error.

Here is Laravel Version Compatibility with this package(*yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle*)

```
Laravel Package
4.2.x   3.x
5.0.x   6.x
5.1.x   6.x
5.2.x   6.x
5.3.x   6.x
5.4.x   7.x, 8.x
5.5.x   8.x
5.6.x   8.x
5.7.x   8.x
5.8.x   9.x
6.x.x   9.x
```

Note: Install Package-version as per your laravel framework requirements

Answer (score -1):

laravel-datatables is only compatible up to Laravel 5.7, according to the [composer.json](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/8.0/composer.json).

Change your composer.json to require the 9.0 version:

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0",
```

Comment: The same error with the same library? Double-check the full message to make sure it's not another library causing the error.. If it's the message about the composer.lock that you mentioned on the other answer, delete the lock file and try again.